# Special Character in Powershell from C#

Tags: c#, powershell, command-prompt

I need to run this command from C#

```
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"}
```

and i use this code:

```
Runspace runspace2 = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
runspace2.Open();
Pipeline pipeline2 = runspace2.CreatePipeline();
pipeline2.Commands.AddScript("Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers | Foreach {Add-AppxPackage -DisableDevelopmentMode -Register \"$($_.InstallLocation)\\AppXManifest.xml\"}");
pipeline2.Invoke();
runspace2.Close();
```

The code return error:

```
C:\AppXManifest.xml not Found
```

But if i run this command from powershell it work and install all Apps so i think is an error for special characters in this part `"$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml"`, suggestions?

Comment: More double quotes around string...

Comment: No error from VS

Comment: Is `C:\AppXManifest.xml` the correct path?

Comment: runspace might not have access to the root of the c: drive.

Comment: Ok i need change to cmd, thanks

Comment: Check `Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers|? {$_.InstallLocation -eq $null}` or even `Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers|? {-not  (Test-Path  "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml")}` and run only `Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers|? {(Test-Path  "$($_.InstallLocation)\AppXManifest.xml")}`